# Type casting when standardising a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a dataframe of two columns (Year, Time) that are integers value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

male100 = pd.read_csv('data/male100.csv', header = 0)

time_mean = male100['Time'].mean()
time_std = male100['Time'].std()

year_mean = male100['Year'].mean()
year_std = male100['Year'].std()


elem_nb = male100.shape[0]

for i in range(elem_nb):
    male100.at[i, 'Year'] = male100.at[i, 'Year'] - year_mean
    male100.at[i, 'Year'] = male100.at[i, 'Year'] / year_std

print(male100)
```

My standard deviation `year_std` is a float value and my mean `year_mean` is an integer. 
At this stage, `male100` should return float values for elements of `Year` column. **However, this is not the case as shown below.**

```
    Year   Time
0     -1  12.00
1     -1  11.00
2     -1  11.00
3     -1  11.20
4     -1  10.80
5     -1  10.80
6      0  10.80
7      0  10.60
8      0  10.80
9      0  10.30
10     0  10.30
11     0  10.30
12     0  10.40
13     0  10.50
14     0  10.20
15     0  10.00
16     0   9.95
17     0  10.14
18     0  10.06
19     0  10.25
20     0   9.99
21     0   9.92
22     1   9.96
23     1   9.84
24     1   9.87
25     1   9.85
26     1   9.69
```

I suppose there is an automatic casting here `male100.at[i, 'Year'] = male100.at[i, 'Year'] / year_std` but can't see why. Or maybe this has something to do with changing the data type of a DataFrame.

How can I overcome that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
male100.at[i, 'Year'] = float(male100.at[i, 'Year']) / year_std
```

OR

```
male100.at[i, 'Year'] = male100.at[i, 'Year'].astype('float') / year_std
```

**Recommendation**

Also, for subtracting and dividing, no need to iterate a loop, you can simply use

```
male100['Year'] = (male100['Year']-year_mean)/year_std
```

Note that this will also automatically convert your values to float, so no need for converting them to float explicitly as given in first solution.